# Error Calling AnimateWithDuration on a Subview from another ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uicollectionview, subview

I have a subview in a container view, and I am trying to animate it to slide up into the screen when an item in my collection view is selected.
The function to slide up the subview is below

```
func showCastControl() {
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5) { () -> Void in
        self.castControlViewController.frame.origin.y = 584
    }
}
```

This slides up the subview.
I am calling it from the view controller that controls the collection view in the `didSelectItem()`. I called the container view controller, which contains the animate function and assigned it to the variable `gcvc`. Then I call the animate function when an item is selected in the collection view:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! PhotosCollectionViewCell
    let photoToCast = self.images[indexPath.row]
    photosToCast.append(photoToCast)
    print("selected a photo")
    print(photosToCast.count)

    if photosToCast .isEmpty == false {
        gcvc.showCastControl()
    }
}
```

The problem is the application crashes and I get a fatal error:

```
unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an optional value
```

This error is highlighted as occurring in the implementation of the show cast control function which is in the container view controller.

The animation works fine when I hide the subview in `viewDidAppear`, but when I call it from the other view controller that controls the collection view, I get the error.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: what is `self.castControlViewController`? If it is a UIView, why did you name it ...viewController? This may not relate to your question directly but you should avoid doing that.

Comment: I guess I should remove the controller in the name. Thanks

Comment: I suggest check whether `castControlViewController` is nil when `showCastControl()` is called. If `castControlViewController` is nil, try to figure out why it is nil, then the issue can be fixed. My guess: As you said,  `The animation works fine when I hide the subview in **viewDidAppear**, `, may be when you call animation from other view controller, the `castControlViewController` hasn't been constructed yet, so you got nil here.

Answer (score 0):

I also develop `UITextfield` rise up using below format code using `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints`, Use this Code

```
func showCastControl() {

     UIView.animateWithDuration(2, delay: 0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseIn, animations: { () -> Void in

          self.castControlViewController.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true

          self.castControlViewController.frame = CGRectMake(0, 558, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)

        }) { (Bool) -> Void in

    }
}
```

this type of code is working perfectly without issues, hope its helpful

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The problem I get is not the animation. Like I mentioned the animation works when I call it from the viewDidAppear of the container view controller. When I call it from the UICollectionViewController is when I get the error.